# Friendly url using htaccess, the last variable is also a friendly url

Tags: .htaccess

I would need from this address

```
something.com/index.php?page=blog_single&id_blog=15&name=friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article
```

to

```
something.com/friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article
```

I tried using htaccess:

```
RewriteRule  ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=blog_single&id_blog=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

but it doesn't work as expected, can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please do mention your friendly URL's sample more clearly in your question so that it will be easier for us to understand that how in backend we need to pass parameters? Thank you.

Comment: The URL you want to use does not contain the ID you are trying to assign to `id_blog`. So where should the content of `$1` come from? The rewriting engine cannot somehow magically guess it... So you will have to come up with a different URL scheme that contains all information required to process the request.

Answer (score 0):

as arkascha commented, your $2 has no definition. I'll propose 2 ways:

1. id_blog is fixed at 15:

`# here $1 is friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article:
RewriteRule  ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=blog_single&id_blog=15&name=$1 [L]`

It does this

> something.com/friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article =>
>
> something.com/index.php?page=blog_single&id_blog=15&name=friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article

2. id_blog is variable:

`# here $1 is id_blog, $2 is friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article:
RewriteRule  ^([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=blog_single&id_blog=$1&name=$2 [L]`

It does this

> something.com/15/friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article =>
>
> something.com/index.php?page=blog_single&id_blog=15&name=friendly-url-the-name-of-the-article